# Mapping sets on labels data structure in Python

Tags: python, search, data-structures

I have a set of keywords that looks like `S = {'apples', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'lemons'}`and I want to associate a label `fruit` to this set in order to classify them basing on the set membership function: `return 'fruit' if x in S`. I have many such sets and corresponding labels. The sets have empty intersections. Is there a data structure that may serve the best for such a purpose? The only idea coming to my mind is to loop over all sets and compute the membership function. Is it possible to implement something like inverted dictionary - knowing one of values gives a key?

Comment: probably you can just use a big `dict`

Comment: how could I do that? It is like i need inverted dictionary - I need to get a key from values

Comment: Your *words* would be the keys, and your label would be the value. See the answer I posted.

Comment: Can a set be a key?

Comment: well, a `frozenset` can be a key, but you don't want that. You want a mapping from words to label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have some sets of words and labels :

```
>>> S1 = {'apples', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'lemons'}
>>> l1 = 'fruit'
>>> S2 = {'lettuce', 'tomato', 'carrot'}
>>> l2 = 'veggies'
```

Aggregate these into some container:

```
>>> sets_and_labels = [(S1, l1), (S2, l2)]
```

Build a dictionary:

```
>>> map = {k:l for s, l in sets_and_labels for k in s}
>>> map
{'bananas': 'fruit', 'lettuce': 'veggies', 'carrot': 'veggies', 'lemons': 'fruit', 'apples': 'fruit', 'tomato': 'veggies', 'grapes': 'fruit'}
>>> map['lemons']
'fruit'
>>> map['carrot']
'veggies'
>>>
```

Note, this works well if as you've stated, the pairwise intersection of the sets is  empty.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need. The only problem, the variable map may become very large due to repetitions

Comment: @freude how large is large? I mean, you are already storing everything already. If you use the dict-comprehension, it won't copy the strings, so it shouldn't be substantial. Also, if you are on Python3.6 the new `dict` implementation is substantially more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If the primary use case is going from keyword to set name (i.e. 'apples' -> fruit), you should probably have a single dict that looks like:

```
{'apples': 'fruit', 'bananas': 'fruit',...}
```

You could use a constant to represent the categories instead but I suspect that string interning will make this not much worse (if at all).